# PHP MySQL display image from database

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi I have form to make new article with informations and image. I susccesfuly save all info and image to database (i guess). And when I want to display info and image so only info works.
See in picture.

Any help? Thanks a lot

[image: Picture]

Inserting_post.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>APK Market</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/style.css">
<link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <form method="post" action="insert_post.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="new_post">
<div class="headtitle">Insert new post</div>
 <div class="new_title">
<p>New title</p>
<input type="text" name="title">
 </div>
 <div class="new_author">
<p>Author</p>
<input type="text" name="author">
 </div>
 <div class="new_keywords">
<p>Keywords</p>
<input type="text" name="keywords">
   </div>
   <div class="new_image">
<p>Image</p>
<input type="file" name="image">
  </div>
  <div class="new_content">
<textarea name="content" cols="20" rows="8"></textarea>
   </div>
  <div class="submit">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">
  </div>
  </div>
 </form>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
   <?php
   include("../includes/connect.php");

   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
$games_date = date('y-m-d-h');
$games_title = $_POST['title'];
$games_author = $_POST['author'];
$games_keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
$games_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$games_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$games_content = $_POST['content'];

if($games_title=="" or $games_author=="" or $games_keywords==""
     or $games_content=="")
{
    echo"<script>alert('any field is empty')</script>";
    exit();
}
else 
move_uploaded_file($games_tmp,"../uploaded_images/$games_image");
$insert_query= "insert into games(games_title,games_date,games_author,games_image,
    games_keywords,games_content)

      values ('$games_title','$games_date','$games_author','$games_image',
   '$games_keywords','$games_cont         ent')";

      }
         if(mysql_query($insert_query))
{
    echo "<center><h1>Post published seccesfuly!</h1></center>";
}
     ?>

     display page:

      <div class="content">
   <?php
     include('connect.php');

    $select_posts = "select * from games";
   $run_posts = mysql_query($select_posts);

   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run_posts))
     {
echo '<p class="games_title_result">' .$games_title = $row['games_title'];
echo '<p class="games_image_result"><img src="<?php echo $row["games_image"];?>';
echo '<p class="games_content_result">' .$games_content = $row['games_content'];
echo '<p class="games_date_result">' .$games_date = $row['games_date'];
echo '<p class="games_author_result">' .$games_author = $row['games_author'];
     }
    ?>  
    </div>
```

Comment: can you give us an example `games_image` value from your database? also tell us where's your folder image is. the directory.

Comment: I don't know if I understand. games_image value from database?

Comment: and directory is: ../uploaded_images/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my answer:

```
echo '<p class="games_image_result"><img src="uploaded_images/'.$row["games_image"].'" />';
```

You got a syntax error where you include a `<?php` and `?>` inside your php, and on your echo at that.

So when you look at your img's src, it would have those.

Also, you forgot to close your img tag and your other p tags.

Comment: reread my post again, you might have missed something when i edited it.

Comment: and if I want to have this image in width: x px and height: x px where I must put it?

Comment: `<img src="uploaded_images/smiley.png" width="100" height="100" />` or throught CSS. or inline-style --- don't forget to vote my post as best answer. tick the check mark. :)

Comment: and i upvote your wonderful and best and immaginary answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your image tag isn't closed properly and the path to the image is not complete. You are only specifying the filename. I am not sure about your directory structure

```
echo '<p class="games_image_result"><img src="uploaded_images/<?php echo $row["games_image"];?>" />';
```

Comment: first time I have this:

Comment: echo '<p class="games_image_result"><img src="<?php echo $row["games_image"];?>';

Answer (score 0):

Display Image from DataBase using php

```
           # SQL Statement
           $sql = "SELECT `idimage` FROM `yourTableName` WHERE id=" . mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . ";";
           $result = mysqli_query("$sql") or die("Invalid query: " . mysqli_error());

           # Set header
           header("Content-type: image/your image name which type of your image");
           echo mysqli_result($result, 0);
      }
      else
           echo 'Please check the ID!';
 ?>
```

I wish it's may be help you